# How to add/update birthday to contact programatically

Tags: android, contacts

I am developing an app in which i need to take birthday from app and add/update into birthday of contact. I have seen around at stackoverflow , found few help but not able to add/update the birthday. I am using following code , but this code did not do anything and neither it raise any kind of exception. Any help would be appreciated.

```
   try {

        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, Integer.valueOf(mContact.getmDeviceId()))
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE, "26-05-2015")
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY)
                .build());

        databaseMasnager.getAllContact();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**,

When your application inserts a new event, we recommend that you use an INSERT Intent, as described in Using an intent to insert an event. However, if you need to, you can insert events directly [refer here.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html)

For a simple example with explanation [Check.](http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2015/07/android-add-calendar-event.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply i dont want to set any reminder or event in calender. I want to add it in contact's tab. In native contact user can see the event by opening contact's detail.

Comment: then you might [try this](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/1/)  and [also](https://www.pocketmagic.net/android-contacts-invoke-the-edit-contact-intent/)